# How to call onPress function in for loop. in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, for-loop

I am new to react native. I have 3 functions

```
function1()
function2()
function3()
```

and I want to run these 3 functions multiple time on single button onPress. and when user click on 4th time then again 1st function should be run and so on.

here is what I have try. But I am keep gettin red line below 4 and error like this = Identifier expected.ts(1003)

```
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            <Icon onPress={this.function[i]}/>
          }
```

please help what is the best way to do that

Answer (score 1):

You might need to assign a key prop to Icon like this:

```
<Icon key={i} onPress={this.function[i]} />
```

In React, any iterated component has to have a key prop, especially when mapping an array. I suppose it should be same for the for loop.

---

Update: If you loop Icon component, it will render multiple times. But I guess you want only one Icon component to click on. Then you might use states to iterate through functions.

```
<Icon onPress={() => {
    this.function[i]
    if (i === 3) this.setState({ i: 1 })
    else this.setState({ i: i + 1 })
}} />
```

Don't forget to add this state statement outside render() function:

```
state = { i: 1 }
```

Comment: but what about that error .  red line below 4 and error like this = Identifier expected.ts(1003)

Comment: I suggested key prop because of the Identifier keyword, because key prop identifies the component when iterated. However, I think the approach should be different, please see the update on my answer.